# Preventing repeated values in magic squares

Tags: c

So I wanted to create a 3x3 magic square generator with certain parameters the problem can be solved using recursion as demonstrated by the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void magic_square(int *grid, int next_slot, int max_value) 
{
    // Maybe recurse
    if (next_slot < 9) 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < max_value; i++) 
        {
            grid[next_slot] = i;
            magic_square(grid, next_slot + 1, max_value);
        }
        // Test magic square.
    } 
    else 
    {
        const int sum = grid[0] + grid[1] + grid[2];
        // Horizontal lines
        if (grid[3] + grid[4] + grid[5] != sum) return;
        if (grid[6] + grid[7] + grid[8] != sum) return;
        // Vertical lines
        if (grid[0] + grid[3] + grid[6] != sum) return;
        if (grid[1] + grid[4] + grid[7] != sum) return;
        if (grid[2] + grid[5] + grid[8] != sum) return;
        // Diagonal lines
        if (grid[0] + grid[4] + grid[8] != sum) return;
        if (grid[2] + grid[4] + grid[6] != sum) return;
        // Guess it works
        printf("%3d %3d %3d\n%3d %3d %3d\n%3d %3d %3d\n\n",
        grid[0], grid[1], grid[2],
        grid[3], grid[4], grid[5],
        grid[6], grid[7], grid[8]);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int grid[9];
    int max_value = 9;
    magic_square(grid, 0, max_value);
}
```

The problem with the code is that the squares it generates contains repeated numbers and I only want magic squares with non-repeated numbers. What I tried to do is introduce a flag at the end and print the grid only if it does not have repeated values but for some reason it did not work.

How do I solve the problem? (Please excuse my rudimentary knowledge of C)
Let us assume the max value is always $9$ as otherwise it can cause problems as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: If you start `int i` at `next_slot ` you will avoid repeating what you have used. What is `max_value` for? If it's 5, your `for` loop won't go above 5.

Comment: @doctorlove max_value is just the maximum number that can be used to fill a magic square.

Comment: If you have a 3 by 3 square and a maximum of five, you need repeats

Comment: ... or negative numbers

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I have added an edit.